# Export CoreData to CSV in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I want the user to be able to export all of their "DiaryItem" CoreData records into a CSV. Here's My code:

**DiaryItem.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class DiaryItem:NSManagedObject,Identifiable {
   @NSManaged public var createdAt:Date?
   @NSManaged public var title:String?
}

extension DiaryItem {
    static func getAllDiaryItems() -> NSFetchRequest<DiaryItem> {
        let request:NSFetchRequest<DiaryItem> = DiaryItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<DiaryItem>

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        return request
     }
}
```

**SettingsView.swift**

```
    import SwiftUI
    import CoreData

    struct SettingsView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: DiaryItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DiaryItem.createdAt, ascending: false),
    ]) var diaryItems : FetchedResults<DiaryItem>

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Button(action: {
                  self.exportDatabase()
               }) {
                  Text("Export")
                  }
        }
    }

    func exportDatabase() {
        let exportString = createExportString()
        saveAndExport(exportString: exportString)
    }

    func saveAndExport(exportString: String) {
        let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "itemlist.csv"
        let exportFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: exportFilePath, contents: NSData() as Data, attributes: nil)
        //var fileHandleError: NSError? = nil
        var fileHandle: FileHandle? = nil
        do {
            fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: exportFileURL as URL)
        } catch {
            print("Error with fileHandle")
        }

       if fileHandle != nil {
            fileHandle!.seekToEndOfFile()
            let csvData = exportString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        fileHandle!.write(csvData!)

        fileHandle!.closeFile()

        let firstActivityItem = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
            UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
            UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
            UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
            UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
        ]
    }
}

func createExportString() -> String {
    var createdAt: Date?
    var title: String?

    var export: String = NSLocalizedString("createdAt, title \n", comment: "")
    for diaryItem in self.diaryItems {

            let createdAtvar = DiaryItem.value(forKey: "createdAt") as! Date?
            let titlevar = DiaryItem.value(forKey: "title") as! String?
            let createdAtString = createdAtvar
            let titleString = titlevar

            export += "\(titleString!),\(createdAtString!)\n"

    }
    print("This is what the app will export: \(export)")
    return export
    }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately when I run this in the simulator it crashes with the error:

> [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator:

I've been banging my head against it for hours any help would be hugely appreciated!!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you cannot be using Swift 4, since SwiftUI is only available in Swift 5.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks! I've updated.

Comment: You don't need to add the Swift version to your question if you are using the latest version. If you omit the version, every assumes it is about the latest version :) Only use version-specific tags if you are asking about a specific change in a new version or if you are asking about an old version.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Ah okay, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Did you find a solution already?

Comment: @gurehbgui No I haven't! Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your SwiftUI View is probably part of another view hierarchy (e.g. a sheet) and doesn't know about the managedObjectContext.

You need to set the moc as part of its environment in the view that opens it, something like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
        SheetView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt look like anyone answered this so ill give it a shot.

I see nowhere in the code you have shown where you are formatting the data from core data into a csv(comma separated value) format.
If you want it to save in the proper format you need to ensure that it follows the standard conventions of a csv document.

Just make sure every column is represented by a comma and every row is represented by a line break.

As long as you conform to the csv standard and save the file with the proper extension it should work.

You will probably need to create some domain models to ensure your entities